# Setup complex VPN connection on Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, vpn, certificate

I have managed to setup the VPN connection on Linux using `Cisco Anyconnect Secure Mobility Client`. I've just put the `.key`, `.crt` and `.pem` certs into the directories

```
/home/user/.cisco/certificates/client/
```

and

```
/home/user/.cisco/certificates/client/private/
```

Also I have moved the CA cert into

```
/opt/.cisco/certificates/ca/
```

And the cisco `.xml` profile went to

```
/opt/cisco/anyconnect/profile/
```

Then I am able to connect to the VPN just by typing my private key, user name, pass and 2fa code.

---

Now I'd like to switch to a Windows system, but I can't find the appropriate program to set it up like on Linux. Unfortunately Windows' *Cisco Anyconnect* gives me only one option: to enter the VPN address and the user/pass.